# How can I get the active ESSID on an interface?

Tags: python, linux, wireless

I wish to get the active ESSID on an interface using only the Python standard library; I only need to support Linux environments. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using the [`SIOCGIWESSID`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/uapi/linux/wireless.h#L271) [`ioctl`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/ioctl.2.html) call.

This code may look a little confusing as it's more akin to something you'd see in C code rather than Python, but it essentially works by first allocating some memory in the form of a Python array (in which we will place the ESSID), and then executing an `ioctl` call which modifies that array in-place.

```
import array
import fcntl
import socket
import struct

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
maxLength = {
    "interface": 16,
    "essid": 32
}
calls = {
    "SIOCGIWESSID": 0x8B1B
}

def getESSID(interface):
    """Return the ESSID for an interface, or None if we aren't connected."""
    essid = array.array("c", "\0" * maxLength["essid"])
    essidPointer, essidLength = essid.buffer_info()
    request = array.array("c",
        interface.ljust(maxLength["interface"], "\0") +
        struct.pack("PHH", essidPointer, essidLength, 0)
    )
    fcntl.ioctl(sock.fileno(), calls["SIOCGIWESSID"], request)
    name = essid.tostring().rstrip("\0")
    if name:
        return name
    return None
```